# Creating Windows Service

Tags: windows, service, jar

I want to create a very simple service in Windows.

The service should simply run a Batch file, which starts a Java application (from jar).

How do i this Simple service for Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [RunAsService.](http://runasservice.sourceforge.net/). It will work for you